# MSAL / AAD gives "Are you trying to sign in to [AppName]" message when using different (Edge-like) user-agent string

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, exchangewebservices, azure-ad-msal

We have a windows application that uses MSAL.NET AcquireTokenInteractive.  We've registered the application in Azure to get a token for use with EWS.  Everything works fine, and the user will not see any prompts, just a flash as the MSAL window will open and close quickly - presuming the Azure admin authorized the app, and the user is logged in or has a valid cached token.

We have a user-agent override setting for our application, and we applied the override to MSAL, and when we pass a different user-agent string (for example, to mimic Edge), everything still works EXCEPT the user does get a prompt -- in the MSAL window it will say "Are you trying to sign in to [app name]?  Only continue if you downloaded the app from a store or website that you trust.  Cancel / Continue "  We suspect this prompt is coming from AAD.

Does anyone know why changing the user-agent string in MSAL would cause this kind of prompt?